# Entity framework update shows dbconcurrency while updating a record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

in my code the update takes place both in the view and in the controller. Same Controller and View for both create and Update. Create profile works fine. but while updating it shows DbConcurrency exception Message. Please help me to find.

Exception Message while updating the record:
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

My Update profile page has (Profile.cshtml)

```
@model Sitecss.Models.Profile
           @using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateProfile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLay.cshtml";
}



@{
    var GT = new SelectList(new[] {
        new {ID ="Team DeathMatch", Name="Team DeathMatch"},
        new {ID ="Search & Destroy", Name="Search & Destroy"},
        new {ID ="Flag Runner", Name="Flag Runner"},
        new {ID ="Domination", Name="Domination"},
        new {ID ="Kill Confirmed", Name="Kill Confirmed"}
    },"ID","Name");
    var Spec = new SelectList(new []{
        new {ID ="Assault", Name="Assault"},
        new {ID ="Tactical", Name="Tactical"},
        new {ID ="Long-Range Eliminations", Name="Long-Range Eliminations"},
        new {ID ="Noob", Name="Noob"}
    }, "ID", "Name");

}


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProfile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div id="content1">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<h4>Create a Profile</h4>

    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SteamName)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SteamName, new { @class = "wide" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SteamName)
    </div>

    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.UserImg)
    </div>
    <div>

    <input type="file" name="image" class="image" /> <br />
    </div>

    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GameType)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GameType, GT, new { @class = "wide" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GameType)
    </div>

    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Specialist)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Specialist, Spec, new { @class = "wide" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Specialist)
    </div>

    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FavGun)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FavGun, new { @class = "wide" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FavGun)
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="button" value="Ok" /></p>
    </div>
}
```

while my controller functions are

```
public ActionResult CreateProfile()
        {
            if (db.Profiles.Any(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name))
            {
                Profile pro = (from usr in db.Profiles where usr.Username == User.Identity.Name select usr).Single();
                olf = pro.UserImg;
                Profile p = db.Profiles.Find(pro.Id);
                ViewBag.ProfilePic = olf;
                return View(p);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Name = User.Identity.Name;
                return View();
            }
        }


   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateProfile(Profile m)
        {
            WebImage photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();

            string newFileName = "";
            string thumbs = "";
            if (photo != null)
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName);
                newFileName = User.Identity.Name+ ext;
                thumbs = @"Images/" + newFileName;
                photo.Resize(width: 120, height: 120, preserveAspectRatio: true, preventEnlarge: true);
                photo.Save(@"~/"+thumbs);
                m.UserImg = newFileName;
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {    
                if (db.Profiles.Any(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name))
                {   

                    db.Entry(m).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

                }
                else
                {
                    m.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                    db.Profiles.Add(m);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            return View(m);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer to show for other readers that the problem is solved? You can accept then your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Adding Breakpoint to the update statement in my edit Controller I came to know that the primary key Id =0 on update in order to fix this issue I have added Hidden Field in the view that has fixed the DbConcurrency on update